# Connect discrete points together in a plot using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

If I have the following figure :

[image]

created by the code :

```
for t=1:length(s)  % s is a struct with over 1000 entries
    plot(t,r1,'k'); % r1 = (0,100,150,170) + 1050
    plot(t,r2,'g'); % r2 = (0,300,350,370) + 1050
    plot(t,r3,'b'); % r3 = (0,200,250,270) + 1050
    plot(t,r4,'m'); % r4 = (0,1000,1250,1500) + 1050
    plot(t,max,'r'); % max = 2000
end
```

Each dot is actually propagating from 1050 to their current value. But you can't see it this way and hence why I would like for a line to be drawn to connect them all.

How can I connect discrete points of the same line together ?

Comment: What are `r1` ... `r4` and `max`? Do they depend on `s`? Do you want horizontal lines, vertical lines, or something else?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Updated question. Well connect them together when they move from various values... 0->100 will create two points, at 0 and 100.. and visually that's hard to see. So a diagonal line that connects these too will make it visually better to understand what's going on

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but why not just create a new vector with all the values you want to plot, and plot the whole thing at once? Then MATLAB will connect them for you. Alternatively you could use a stem plot. Also, it's a bad idea to use max as a variable name as it is a built in function.

Comment: @wakjah Oh, you mean remove it from the for loop ?? If you can reply as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @wakjah I just tried that, stored all values in an array during the for loop and plotted after, same thing, nothing changed.

Comment: Well I would, but I don't really understand how `r1...4` differ between different values of `t` so I'm not confident about writing any code for you.

Comment: @wakjah There are IF statements in the For loop that dictate what value are chosen (between 0 and the others). t is incremented as to imitate time increase while plotting. Let me know if you still need the IF statements.

Answer (score 1):

Does this give the result that you want?

```
for t=1:length(s)  % s is a struct with over 1000 entries
    a(t,:)=r1; % r1 = (0,100,150,170) + 1050  
end
plot(a)
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much !! Can you please explain why this is working ? How come my method doesn;t ?

Comment: Your method plots individual, independent points for each iteration of the loop. If you create an array first like I did, and then plot it, Matlab knows how to connect the points.

Comment: I noticed that this prints two results at a time .. Why ?? for example at t=1, a(t,:)=[0 100] rather than just 100 ...